# How do I add numbers in a ORM query in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to fire a **DATEDIFF** query with **SQLAlchemy ORM** where I need to add a variable to the output of **DATEDIFF**

ORM:

```
query = session.query(func.datediff(text("ss"), some_date, another_date) + 1000).all()
```

Desired SQL:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SS, some_date, another_date) + 1000 FROM Table
```

Executing the above ORM query outputs SQL as

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(SS, some_date, another_date) || '' AS anon_1 FROM Table
```

and throws an **ProgrammingError** `"Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'INT' not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query"`

I have tried using `label()` with `func.datediff()` but it did not yield expected results. How can I make this query work ?

Comment: Can you add your Model or DDL for `Table`?

Comment: Also what is `some_date` and `another_date`? They don't indicate "numbers" to me, you may wish to amend your title to indicate the desired datatype.

Comment: They are datetime objects. If result of datediff for example will be 1000 seconds, I'm attempting to select 2000 as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy assumes that `func.datediff` returns a`String`. You need to specify the type:

```
func.datediff(text("ss"), some_date, another_date, type_=Integer) + 1000
```

or force the `+` operator:

```
func.datediff(text("ss"), some_date, another_date).op('+')(1000)
```